# Obter TimeStamp do SQLServer

Tags: android, sql-server

Queria muito pegar o `TimeStamp` do banco de dados SQLServer, porém não estou conseguindo, segue meu exemplo:

```
Connection connUpdate = DriverManager.getConnection(ConnectionURL);
PreparedStatement atualizaDevice = connUpdate.prepareStatement("select current_timestamp");
atualizaDevice.execute();
ResultSet r = atualizaDevice.getResultSet();
Timestamp t = r.getTimestamp(1);
String time = String.valueOf(t);
txtTime.setText(time);
Log.e("TIME", time);
connUpdate.close();
```

Usando esse código retorna o seguinte erro:

> java.sql.SQLException: No current row in the ResultSet.

Alguma ideia do que fazer?

Answer (score 0):

Você tem que selecionar a linha do banco de dados, do jeito que você está fazendo não está selecionando. De uma lida neste artigo: https://andrielleazevedo.wordpress.com/2011/06/06/usando-o-comando-select-no-sql-server/ a Excption retornada está vindo diretamente da falta de seleção de linha

Comment: executando a query no sqlserver ele retorna o resultado normalmente, coloco tbm select current_timestamp as HORA e insiro "HORA" como parâmetro do método, mas mesmo assim ele retorna o mesmo erro